# pass data to api react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm new in reactjs  and I have a clickable div that  I can change the content in the next step I want to pass the data with click on edit button I changed to api ;what should I do

```js
 <div style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} contentEditable="true" className="p-2 ">
  {currentUser.user?.fullName}
 </div>
   <Button variant="success" disabled={!isLoggedIn} className="btn btn-custom w-100 text-center 
  text-black">
      edit
   </Button>
```

?

Comment: Do you have a server with endpoints? Just write a function that is called when the button is clicked which makes [a fetch/POST request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) with the data to an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function that you call when the button is clicked.
To contact your api you can use the [`fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) from Javascript.

And I'm guessing that your `currentUser` object is a state object, so you can just get that object in your function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} contentEditable="true" className="p-2 ">
      {currentUser.user?.fullName}
     </div>
       <Button 
         variant="success" 
         disabled={!isLoggedIn} 
         className="btn btn-custom w-100 text-center text-black"
         onClick={handleUser(currentUser)}
       >
          edit
       </Button>

const handleUser = (data) => {
   console.log(data);
  fetch('API_URL')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
};
```